# php link adding current domain

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
echo "<li style='font-size:10pts;' class='news-item'>
        <a href='$link'>(".date("D, d M Y", strtotime($date)).") $description</a>
      </li>";
```

and the database field value for **link** is:

> www.yahoo.com

Now when the echo statement above is executed, and I click on the link shown on page, it doesn't go to www.yahoo.com, but rather to www.mydomain.com/www.yahoo.com. This of course results in not found 404. How can I solve this please?

Comment: try http:// before the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont add `http://` in front of your link, It will be executed as a directory:

```
echo "<li style='font-size:10pts;' class='news-item'>
        <a href='http://{$link}'>(".date("D, d M Y", strtotime($date)).") $description</a>
      </li>";
```

Or put `http://www.yahoo.com/` in your database and use your original script.

Answer (score 2):

Put into database link with http://

Answer (score 1):

add http or https ahead of link href.

```
$var = 'www.yahoo.com';

if(strpos($var, 'http://') !== 0) {
  return 'http://' . $var;
} else {
  return $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$link = "http://".$link;

<a href='".$link."'>(".date("D, d M Y", strtotime($date)).") $description</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `http://` to the beginning otherwise it is **relative to the current location**

Answer (score 0):

Your `$link = "www.yahoo.com"`

your code  `<a href='$link'>`

then  output  `<a href='www.yahoo.com'>`

When you use  tag a href attribute should be  `<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>` 
to link to other domain.